# User Messaging Platform 2.0.0 release crashes

Tags: android

I updated from

```
implementation 'com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:1.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.0.0'
```

And now I receive in crashlytics many crashes (this happens only for users from Europe, that's why I published and didn't notice on my own devices):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError
Verifier rejected class wa.f: java.lang.Object wa.f.h(java.lang.Object) failed to verify
...
com.google.android.gms.internal.consent_sdk.zzu.run (zzu.java:38)
com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdvf.run$bridge (zzdvf.java:38)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Also here https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/VPUtbIGgEYw

p.s. temporary downgraded to 1.0.0 version...

Comment: looks like bug. Raise an issue.

Answer (score 2):

This proguard rule, fix crash for my app:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.consent_sdk.** { <fields>; }
```

Comment: This will keep only fields

Answer (score 0):

Try add rule in proguard

`-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }`

Comment: well it's too much (too many classes will be excluded), Google have to fix it or provide official produarg rules for this library

Answer (score 0):

I used for fix:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.consent_sdk** { *; }
```

Or you can use

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.consent_sdk.zzas { *; }
```

but this very dangerous

Comment: well it's too much (too many classes will be excluded), Google have to fix it or provide official produarg rules for this library